# Intent handler does not work when multiple intents have scores higher than default threshold

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

The high scoring intent is not handled when multiple LUIS intents have their respective scores higher than the default threshold(0.1). For example, this is the LUIS response I'm receiving:

```
"entities": [],
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "Good",
      "score": 0.38138606327968266
    },
    {
      "intent": "Not Good",
      "score": 0.14239219383059437
    },
    {
      "intent": "getInfo1",
      "score": 0.058470389996233038
    },
    {
      "intent": "getInfo3",
      "score": 0.052354321946208544
    },
    {
      "intent": "End Conversation",
      "score": 0.051956717501244802
    },
    {
      "intent": "getInfo2",
      "score": 0.049671852402879912
    },
    {
      "intent": "getInfo4",
      "score": 0.04166953247839323
    },
    {
      "intent": "getInfo5",
      "score": 0.032684937293639832
    },
    {
      "intent": "getInfo6",
      "score": 0.027630602530947044
    },
    {
      "intent": "getInfo7",
      "score": 0.027075797198458249
    }
  ],
  "query": "iam good",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "Good",
    "score": 0.38138606327968266
  }
}
```

I believe that the below intents are getting into some kind of conflict as they both have scores > 0.1.
I tried adding `intentThreshold` parameter for the `triggerAction` of the respective handlers. However, it is of no use.

> { "intent": "Good", "score": 0.38138606327968266 }, { "intent": "Not
>   Good", "score": 0.14239219383059437 }

**Code Example**

```
//BOT REST end point
var server = restify.createServer(options);
server.listen(config.port,function() {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
});

var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: config.BOTFRAMEWORK_APPID, 
    appPassword: config.BOTFRAMEWORK_APPSECRET
});
server.post('/test', connector.listen());

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(config.model);

bot.recognizer(recognizer);

bot.dialog("/",[function(session){
  if(utilities.isEmpty(session.userData.name)) {
    // Greetings
    builder.Prompts.text(session,prompt.greeting_text);
    }else {
          session.beginDialog("/beginConversation");
    }
  },
  function(session,results){
    session.userData.name = results.response;
    console.log("username :"+ session.userData.name);
    session.beginDialog("/beginConversation");
}]);
// beginConversation
bot.dialog("/beginConversation", function(session){
  builder.Prompts.text(session,"Hello "+session.userData.name+"! "+prompt.conversation_begin_text);
});

// userGood
bot.dialog("/userGood", function(session){
  session.userData.isHappy = true;
  builder.Prompts.text(session,prompt.user_good_response_text+" "+prompt.address_query_text);
}).triggerAction({
  matches: "Good",
  intentThreshold:0.20
});
// userBad
bot.dialog("/userBad", function(session){
  session.userData.isHappy = false;
  builder.Prompts.text(session,prompt.user_bad_response_text+" "+prompt.address_query_text);
}).triggerAction({
  matches: "Not Good",
  intentThreshold:0.20
});
```

Conversation flow:

> User: Hi Bot: Greetings from bot! Please tell me your name
>
> User: John Doe
>
> Bot: Hello John Doe! How’re you doing ?
>
> User: Iam good

I believe that the intent handler corresponding to the highest scoring intent should always be triggered. The bot should respond based on this intent handler.

However, there is no response as multiple intents surpass the default intent threshold, despite explicitly setting the `intentThreshold` parameter of `triggerAction` to a different threshold value.

Am I doing something wrong here ?

**SDK Version: 3.8.4**

Comment: Did you train your LUIS model to recognize the non-word "Iam"? What training data did you use in your LUIS app to determine what is "Good" vs. "Not Good"? What is the purpose of the 7 intents "getInfo1" - "getInfo7"?

Comment: If all you are trying to do is have the user choose between "good" and "not good" - you can easily accomplish this with a choice prompt without using LUIS at all. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-prompt

Comment: @NilsW I haven't trained LUIS to recognize "Iam". However, that just an example I wanted to cite here. I see that whenever the intent score is less than 0.5, the handler is not invoked. Also, regarding the 7 intents `getInfo1` to `getInfo7` , these are for addressing several feature related queries as the bot is expected to address product related queries. Thanks for your inputs.